# Oracle 12c Release 2: Environment variable: "PATH" Status: Failed

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

So I am trying to install oracle 12c in my Windows 10 x64 Dell laptop, but I keep getting the following error:

[image: Error]

[image: Details]

I have tried the following but none of them succeeded:

1. Deleting directories from Path to shorten it.
2. Running cmd as an administrator and executing the setup.exe from there.
3. Renaming Path to PATH.
4. Restarted laptop several times in order for the changes to apply.

What am I missing here?

Comment: My standard response to any issues encountered under Windows is to reboot.

Comment: Do you have any other versions of Oracle installed? I had a similar issue installing Oracle 12c recently. It was caused by having Oracle Express also installed and there was some kind of conflict. Have you tried ignoring the error and proceeding?

Comment: No other version of Oracle is installed in my laptop. I have not tried that. Do you suggest it?